# Multiple outputs for "apt-cache policy <package name>"

Tags: command-line, package-management, apt-cache

From what I understand, `apt-cache policy <package name>` displays the pinning order and thus the releases of `package name` available in the apt repositories along with their priority orders.

So, if for an uninstalled package, the output consists of various versions (with same priority of 500) which one will be the one to be installed?

For example,  `$ apt-cache policy git` yields me:

```
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2
 Version table:
    1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2 500
       500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
       500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
    1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3 500
       500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

So, running `$ sudo apt install git` will install which of the versions in my system?

Comment: The `focal-update` and `focal-security

Answer (score 1):

"Candidate" indicates the version that will be installed.

It's always the highest version if different ones are available from different repositories. In the specific case of your question it comes from the "focal-updates/main" repository that you manually enabled. Disable it if you want to current version instead of the backport.

Answer (score 1):

Choose between the two versions:

```
1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2
1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3
```

Version x3.2 is higher than x3, so `1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2` will be installed...unless something on your system *requires* version x3.

---

Choose between different pockets that offer the same version:

```
500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
```

Ha -- it's a trick question: The repositories are structured so that all packages sit in one directory (/pool). Both lines point to the *same package* in the pool.

Comment: "unless something on your system requires version x3"

Will that not be displayed by the priority number or the entries in ``/etc/apt/preferences`` to determine the one to be installed?

Comment: Dependencies do not establish priority. Dependencies come first. If multiple packages satisfy dependencies, then version number. If the same version is available from multiple sources, then priority.